# How to set a button to pay a fee with address and amount already set in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to code in solidity a pay fee function like so:

```
contract GetFee {

    address payable public feeCollector = 0x59c0f4Bea65c99C281A0107C86beE309b20b3B49;

    function payFee() public payable {
        feeCollector.transfer(100000000000000000);
    }
}
```

However when I click it in solidity I get the following error:

```
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
```

If I do however insert any amount in the deploy & run, like 1 ETH for example, it works, but I don't want to do that.

I want a function that when clicked it simply send that specific amount to that specific address, without the user having to insert anything else.

How to do that?

Comment: The contract must have the funds to do the transfer. The reason why it works with 1 ETH is beacese that will give the contract enough funds to do so. So the problem you are facing is not a problem just the code following the logic it has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not be done, as any funds transfer must be initiated by the user. There is a workaround in web3 and js.

Answer (score 1):

Its easy. Instead of hard coding the amount, you just put a variable in it. Take a look at code below which takes an address and amount from user, and then sends the amount to the given address:

```
function payFromContract (address payable _recipient, uint _amount) external {
    _recipient.transfer(_amount);
}
```